# How to remove a defined text character from element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove `y` from the text character:

My mark up:

```
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="_sft_category[]" value="" data-sf-cr="_sft_31" data-sf-hide-empty="1"> y2012 <span class="sf-count">(8)</span>
</label>
```

it has to become `2012` and I am trying the following but with no luck

```
$('label input').text(function() {
 var text = $(this).text();
 return text.indexOf('y') == 0 ? text.substring(1) : text;
});
```

There is a blank space in my text output, I wonder if that has something to do as it is " y2012 "

Comment: Why not use replace function of JS `return text.replace("y", ""); `

Comment: Use this instead: `text = text.replace("y", "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting value again in input

```
 $('label input').text(function() {
     var text = $(this).text();
     text = text.replace('y','');
     $(this).val(text);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you can change the original markup instead of fixing it using javascript that will be better.

In this case it is not the input element's text, it is the contents of a text node so

```js
var $input = $('label input'),
    elTxt = $input[0].nextSibling;
elTxt.nodeValue = elTxt.nodeValue.replace(/^(\s)?y/, '$1')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"> y2012
</label>
```

Comment: for a number of reasons i won't be able to remove the letter

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
return text.replace("y", "")
```